# What are all the possible options for gcc's -march=XXX and -mtune=XXX flags?

Tags: gcc

It seems like the docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html are somehow incomplete of the options for -march=XXX (and -mtune=XXX), what are *all* the possible options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK found an updated list, google doesn't take you there, you have to manually find it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options

Appears the list is:

32-bit processors:

```
athlon
athlon-4
athlon-fx
athlon-mp
athlon-tbird
athlon-xp
k6
k6-2
k6-3
geode
c3
c3-2
winchip-c6
winchip2
i386
i486
i586
i686
pentium
pentium-m
pentium-mmx
pentium2
pentium3
pentium3m
pentium4
pentium4m
pentiumpro
prescott
lakemont
```

64 bit processors: (note that you can use this as `march` and `mtune` values for 32-bit compilers, as well).

```
amdfam10
athlon64
athlon64-sse3
barcelona
bdver1
bdver2
bdver3
bdver4
znver1
btver1
btver2
k8
k8-sse3
opteron
opteron-sse3
nocona
core2
corei7
corei7-avx
core-avx-i
core-avx2
atom
slm
nehalem
westmere
sandybridge
ivybridge
haswell
broadwell
bonnell
silvermont
knl
skylake-avx512
x86-64 # this is some kind of "generic 64 bit" option apparently
```

And a few exceptions: -mtune can also have `-mtune=generic` and `-march` can have `-march=native` (native meaning "the same as the compiler box it is being built on")

refs:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/21ecea397b2b4725f89d1693aaa6df74d3dcfa27/gcc/config.gcc#L587

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c7f16cfa30360489a9d42e244cb800c7da0396d9/gcc/config/i386/i386.h#L334

https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/gcccpuopt

You can also visit the documentation of the latest version of GCC, which can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options).

This is a community wiki, feel free to add any that come up later, and or add explanations of what these each mean, if there are any equivalence classes, etc.